Skaffold run fails because skaffold is unable to pull images
I'm running skaffold with minikube in linux (Arch linux). NOT running docker in rootless mode.
I'm able to deploy to minikube and it is working. However, if I run skaffold run, I'm getting the following error:
Generating tags...
 - skaffold-example -> skaffold-example:v2.11.1-1-gba74c3306
Checking cache...
ERRO[0000] retrying dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:45407->[::1]:53: read: connection refused 
ERRO[0000] retrying dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:34557->[::1]:53: read: connection refused 
ERRO[0000] retrying dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:42559->[::1]:53: read: connection refused 
 - skaffold-example: Error checking cache.
getting hash for artifact "skaffold-example": getting dependencies for "skaffold-example": parsing ONBUILD instructions: retrieving image "golang:1.18": Get "https://index.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:42559->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Any help? Thanks
/etc/resolv.conf file in minikube contains nameserver 192.168.49.1. Tried rewriting it with nameserver 8.8.8.8 and it makes no difference and the changes are overwritten anyway when I restart minikube. Tried deleting and creating minikube cluster as well.
